# Django RestFrameWork Security

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

How can I protect my endpoints?

Currently, I'm working on a project but I don't know how to secure the API URLs.

How can I prevent the user from login through the rest framework (backend using the API URL)?
I'm currently using IsAuthenticated but still, it gives a prompt to enter username and password which I want to prevent.

Comment: ”... it gives a prompt to enter username and password which I want to prevent”. Why?

Comment: so that no1 can access the backend apis directly